# Retrieve table ID from selected row

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I've been stuck on this for a while and I can't find anything on google for this *specific* thing.

I have this small snippet of code

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", 'username','password',"database");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `uploads` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1";
```

Which *should* select the latest table by order of id's right?
Well what I want to do is return this id. So if I have 5 items/rows I want to grab the latest (5 in this case) id of the table, and return it. With the eventual goal of using this returned id in javascript but that's a worry for later, right now I just want it in plaintext where the result should *only* be the id.

This is probably a duplicate question but I can't for the life of me find what I should google to get there

**EDIT:**

I guess I should clarify further. I know I'm able to do

```
$sql = "SELECT ID FROM `uploads` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1";
```

but whenever I try to actually retrieve it/print it its returned as a string instead of the ID.

EDIT 2: I, thanks to some comments, have managed to figure it out. Sorry for the badly worded everything, I'm new to this and as I said don't know how to word it.

SOLUTION:

After just throwing away the $sql thing I added:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM `uploads`");
```

Then I simply did

```
echo mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

To echo out the number of rows/what I called the "ID".

Sorry for all the confusion, thanks to those that tried to help. To the others there's no need to be rude.

Comment: `SELECT id FROM ...`

Comment: `LIMIT 0, 1`  *I want to grab the latest (5 in this case)*  your limit should be 5 then

Comment: *"but whenever I try to actually retrieve it/print it its returned as a string instead of the ID."* - That isn't in your post and we don't know what it is you're doing to get that.

Comment: I hope we don't know need to submit an answer in order to get a response here. Are you not paying attention to comments here? I won't be staring at a response for mine above any much longer.

Comment: what "string" you are talking about?

Comment: "SELECT id FROM `uploads` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1" gets returned as a string.

Comment: OMG so you didn't even **execute** this query

Comment: what about looking at at least one manual page / tutorial on how to use mysqli?

Comment: Could you kindly post the DB Structure Here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to get the `ID` field only, so you have two options:

**Option 1 (Recommended)**

Given your code

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `uploads` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1";
```

Change it to:

```
$sql = "SELECT ID FROM `uploads` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1";
```

This way, your getting just that `ID` field you're after. Nothing else is returned from each row.

**Option 2**

Keep your sql query as it is, and get the `ID` field from each row in your results (it's an array, so you can retrieve only one field by using its index or name).

Of course, I assume there's an `ID` field in your table!

Comment: There is an id, although even when I change it to SELECT ID whenever I try to print it (I did a foreach for the first option) it prints out that entire line.

I guess my follow up question is how do I retrieve it from that? Instead of just printing it out as a string?

Comment: Can you post the line you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

Just select the ID.

```
SELECT id
FROM   uploads
ORDER  BY id DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply select what you want.

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM `uploads` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1";
```

The `*` means you want to select every column there is. However, SQL gives you the possibility to select the specific columns you want. You could also do something like

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name, title, somethingelse FROM `uploads` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1";
```

and you'd receive these 4 fields as an array.